# how to determine proper size of average filter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'd like to ask a question in order determining size for average filter. How to determine proper size of average filter using matlab if variance(square of std deviation) = 0.00006 ?

I need to find proper size of average filter to reduce Gaussian noise, I already got the related lecture but I have no idea how to apply it in matlab. This is the related equation that I know:

[image]

Really thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, what is the context here?  The variance of what?  And an average filter for doing what?

Comment: @oli-charleswort, Hi I already modified my question hope it'll be more informative. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That equation is simply relating the input/output noise *ratio* to the number of pixels you're averaging over.  So for instance, if you want to reduce the noise variance by 2, you'll need `m = 2`.

Comment: @oli-charleswort, if I'd like to apply this function >>fs1=fspecial('average',?) in matlab, so how to determine the proper size of average filter?

Comment: @Mr.K: You need to know how much you want to reduce the noise variance (power) by.  Basically, `m = ceil(var_in / var_out);`.

Comment: @oli-charleswort: I set m=3, so if I put the value into above equation, the result is 0.0046. So what should I do next to use >>fs1=fspecial('average',?) in matlab?, in order to determine the proper filter.

Comment: @Mr.K: You give `fspecial` the size of your filter (e.g. `[3 3]`), and it generates you a filter matrix.  But note that these are 2D filters; the number of points you'll be averaging over will be `num_rows*num_cols`.  So if you want a square filter, you'll want each dimension to be `sqrt(m)`.

Comment: @oli-charleswort: I'm still try to finding the relation between equation and fspecial in matlab. I know that filter is [3 3] as a default. Actually this is the real question of my assignment, "In theory, if we wish to reduce the Gaussian noise to v=0.00006 (v = σ2) with average filtering, what should be the size of the Average filter?". Any further idea?

Comment: @Mr.K: You need to know what the variance of the Gaussian noise is *before* the filtering as well.

Comment: @oli-charleswort:Yup, I forgot to mention it here. I already get the desired m value after put prior variance and desired/current variance into equation. Thanks.